# Firefox makes simple jquery slidetoggle() disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, accordion

They wanted to have a simple toggle open close accordion like interaction.  Not trying to reinvent the wheel but just trying to learn jquery/javascript.  Everything is going smoothly until I tested on firefox.  On click my accordion just disappears... is this my fault? jquery's fault? codepen's fault?

[Codepen interaction](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/mCAzy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change js code like this

```
$(".x-button").click(function () {
  $(".inner-info-container").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("x-button p-button");
  return false;//insert this line
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return false` after the `$(this).toggleClass("x-button p-button");`
`return false` just means it doesn't try to go to the href, it stops the normal link behavior.